# Start a systemd user service at system boot instead of at user login

Tags: systemd, systemd-boot, systemd-user

Given a service definition at `~/.config/systemd/user/do-something.service` for UID 1000, which is installed, enabled, and starts automatically **at login**, I would like the `do-something.service` to start **at system boot** instead.

One possible solution would be to install `user@1000.service` as a dependency of the system’s `multi-user.target`, but then the question becomes whether this is a recommended setup and what its downsides are.

Answer (score 9):

As I learned from [the systemd/User entry on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances), starting the user manager at boot is handled by systemd-logind. For the current user:

```
loginctl enable-linger
```

And for a different `USER` (username or ID):

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger USER
```

From [the man page](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html#enable-linger%20USER%E2%80%A6):

> If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services.